# How to list all enabled API services for Google Cloud Platform project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We manage a couple dozen GCP projects, and I've never figured out how to list all the enabled API services for each project on the website. There is a way to do it via Cloud Shell by running the console command: `gcloud services list`

If I visit https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=PROJECT_NAME, I can see whether a specific API service is enabled, but then I'd have to individually visit 300 separate API pages per project, which is not feasible.

There has to be a better way for end users to do that without having to install Google Cloud SDK.

Comment: You can check this in the [APIs & Services dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) itself. It lists all enabled APIs for a project, whether you have used them on not

Comment: That page only lists the enabled API keys (and Service + OAuth accounts), not the enabled API Library services.

Comment: You can see the API Keys in the Credentials page. besed on this documentation (https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/list-services#enabled), for listing all enabled APIs and services in a project, you can check in the  API Dashboard page. It has a same result when you are using this command (gcloud services list)

Comment: Actually, you guys are right. I just never noticed it on the main Dashboard page below the Traffic, Errors, and Latency charts.

Sorry for doubting you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LundinCast and Kamelia Y commented, the enabled API libaries are listed on the main Dashboard page. They're under the Traffic, Errors, and Median latency charts.

[image]

Answer (score 22):

```
gcloud services list --enabled --project <PROJECT>
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow this reference link (1)

(1) https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/list-services#gcloud_1

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/list-services#gcloud_1 is where I found the ```gcloud services list``` command. It works, but it's cumbersome to have to use the Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 1):

On the home dashboard there is a API's Section. If you go to the API's Overview, you'll find it there if you scroll down a bit.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the command:

`gcloud services list --available`

refer the documentation for more details:
https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/list-services#gcloud

Comment: hey Amrit, this lists the available API's, not the enabled ones ;)