# How to get the list of for Google Cloud Platform project with specific API enabled?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are trying to retrieve a list of projects with the "Container Registry API" enabled within my organization.

As mentioned in the link here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62284484/how-to-list-all-enabled-api-services-for-google-cloud-platform-project](https://stackoverflow.com), it is not feasible to visit each project individually.

I have tried using the below bash script:

Below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "ProjectName,ProjectNum" > project-container111.csv

all_projects=$(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")

for project in $all_projects; do
    # Check if the service exists in the project
    matching_service=$(gcloud services list --project="$project" --filter='config.name:containerregistry.googleapis.com' --format='value(config.name)')
    
    if [[ -n "$matching_service" ]]; then
        # Fetch project details and write to CSV
        project_name=$(gcloud projects describe "$project" --format="value(name)")
        project_num=$(gcloud projects describe "$project" --format="value(projectNumber)")
        echo "$project_name,$project_num" >> project-container111.csv
    fi
done
```

And here is the error I got:

```
] is not a valid project ID.property must be set to a valid project ID, [sys-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
To set your project, run:

  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID

or to unset it, run:

  $ gcloud config unset project
```

Comment: Enable debugging and show which line of your script is reporting the error.

Comment: Your project ID seems containing [].  Display it to check the format of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a community wiki by [Gabriel Robledo Ahumada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979872/go-containerregistry-package-lists-gcr-repositories-from-all-projects-organiza) that suggested migrating to [Artifact Registry.](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry) From there you can get a list of repos of a particular project using the list method of the REST resource

[projects.locations.repositories.](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1beta2.projects.locations.repositories)